# How can I fix it so that when I add a NSSplitViewController to the storyboard my window isn't collapsed?

Tags: macos, nssplitviewcontroller

When I add a NSSplitViewController to my document-based storyboard like so:

[image]

It will not respect my minimum content size and collapses instantly. Why is it doing this, is this a bug? And how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: You can simply mimic the behavior. Create a new project, make it document-based with storyboard. Remove the default NSViewController in Storyboard and replace it with a NSSplitViewController. Link the NSSplitViewcontroller to the contentViewController of the NSWindowViewController. Run your app nothing appears to be wrong. Now open a new document (CMD&N) it only has the title bar.

Comment: I already deleted the comments since I did exactly that :))

Comment: I still think you're missing layout constraints. I'd add a n answer, but that sounds too obvious...

Comment: Yea so in order to fix this issue I would need to add a custom view to the top and bottom view controllers and add minimum constraints am I right?

Comment: Let me answer... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the proper constraints to the content of the individual splits. When you don't fill up all the space, you simply add a bottom constraint with `>=`.

When I add all constraints corresponding to the screenshot below, I get the correct widow size.

**EDIT**
Sorry, but I definitely didn't copy you're design properly ;-)

**EDIT II**

I'll add some explanation at this point. With auto layout almost all views determine their size by the content within them. They try to be as narrow as possible, in any axis.

That means if there is no constraint to the views bottom, it will not know about any contents height and thus returns zero for its height.

[image: layout constraints architecture]
[image: resulting window appearance]

Comment: Your design looks better tbh ;-)